# I am porting some C++ standard functions into C# for verification (matching results)

Tags: c#, c++

Can you help me look through the functions below to make sure they behave similarly as these standard C++ functions (`_fcvt`, `ltoa`, `atoi`, `CString(char*)`). The reason is that I am converting some code from `C++` to `C#` and I want to validate that the code works EXACTLY the same. These functions are used in a custom numeric rounding procedure I am looking at.

```
/// <summary>
/// C# port of C++ functions
/// </summary>
public static class LegacyEx
{
    const int _CVTBUFSIZE=50;
    /// <summary>
    /// Port of C++ _fcvt() function. See http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/fcvt.html
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Floating point value to be converted to a string.</param>
    /// <param name="digits">Number of digits to be returned. If this is greater than the number of representable digits the rest of the string is padded with zeros. If this is smaller the low-order digit is rounded.</param>
    /// <param name="decimal">Pointer to an int where to store the decimal-point position respect to the beginning of the string. 0 or less indicates that the decimal point lies to the left of the digits.</param>
    /// <param name="sign">Pointer to an int that receives the sign indicator: 0 means positive sign, non-zero means negative.</param>
    /// <returns>A null-terminated buffer with the legth specified by num that contains the digits of the value.</returns>
    static char[] _fcvt(double value, int digits, out int @decimal, out int sign)
    {
        sign=value>0?0:1; // 0=positive, 1=otherwise
        char[] buffer=new char[_CVTBUFSIZE];
        value=Math.Round(Math.Abs(value),digits); //remove sign and round digits
        string t=value.ToString();
        @decimal=t.IndexOf('.')+@sign; //find index of decimal point
        t=t.Replace(".", string.Empty); //remove decimal point
        Array.Copy(t.ToCharArray(), buffer, t.Length);
        return buffer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Port of C++ ltoa() function. See http://rp-www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/ltoa.html
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be represented as a string.</param>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer where to store the resulting string.</param>
    /// <param name="radix">Numeral radix in which value has to be represented, between 2 and 36.</param>
    /// <returns> A buffer containing the string.</returns>
    static char[] ltoa(long value, ref char[] buffer, int radix)
    {
        // convert value to string of base radix
        string text=Convert.ToString(value, radix);
        // insert result into buffer
        char[] array=text.ToCharArray();
        Array.Copy(array, buffer, array.Length);
        return array;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Port of C++ atoi() function. See http://rp-www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/atoi.html
    /// </summary>       
    /// <param name="text">String representing an integer number.</param>
    /// <returns>The converted integer value of the input string.</returns>
    static int atoi(string text)
    {
        // get rid of whitespace
        text=text.Trim(); 
        // consider up to last digit. This will fail with "12A3" for example
        int count =text.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
        text=text.Substring(0, count);
        int x=0;
        int.TryParse(text, out x);
        return x;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Port of CString(char[]) constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">A null terminated buffer for the string definition.</param>
    /// <returns>The string value from the buffer.</returns>
    static string String(char[] buffer)
    {
        int count=Array.IndexOf(buffer, '\0');
        if(count<0) { count=buffer.Length; }
        return new string(buffer, 0, count);
    }
} // LegacyEx
```

Note: that I cannot directly port `atoi()` for example to `int.Parse()` because in my code it get called with `atoi(".")` at some point and parse fails. Also `atoi()` handles whitespace whereas `int.TryParse()` does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CultureInfo**

Since you convert floating-point numbers to strings, it makes sense to keep in mind that the dot `.` is not the only possible decimal separator. Therefore my advice is to specify the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` each time when converting a floating-point number to string and back.

**About the `_fcvt` method.**

- You don't need to allocate a `buffer` first. And I believe you don't need the `buffer` at all.
- The `value=Math.Abs(value).Round(digits);` doesn't compile for me.
- Instead of the rounding and converting to string, you could use predefined format string (`Fnnn`, where `nnn` - is the number of decimal digits)
- Since we know that there is only 1 dot, I'd prefer to use the `String.Remove` method instead of the `String.Replace`.

My code:

```
static char[] _fcvt(double value, int digits, out int @decimal, out int sign)
{
    sign = value > 0 ? 0 : 1;   // 0=positive, 1=otherwise
    string t = Math.Abs(value).ToString("F" + digits, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int dotPos = t.IndexOf('.');  //find index of decimal point
    @decimal = dotPos + sign;
    t = t.Remove(dotPos, 1);    //remove decimal point
    return t.ToCharArray();
}
```

**About the `atoi` method.**

- You have mistake in the line

  ```
  text = text.Substring(0, count);
  ```

  You should get 1 more char:

  ```
  text = text.Substring(0, count + 1);
  ```
- There is no need to `Trim` the input string. The `int.TryParse` method do it for you.

My code:

```
static int atoi(string text)
{
    // consider up to last digit. This will fail with "12A3" for example
    int count = text.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
    text = text.Substring(0, count + 1);
    int x;
    int.TryParse(text, out x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Yes you need to use `value=Math.Round(Math.Abs(value),digits)` instead of the `.Round()` extension method. My bad.

Comment: Does `Fnnn` formatting round or truncate?

Comment: For `_fcvt()` the original C++ code returns a buffer with `\x0` in the unused spaces and I wanted to mimic this behavior.

Comment: So why should I round in formatting as opposed to use `Math.Round()`?

Comment: Formatting does the same as `Math.Round` - it rounds. And I've never said you *should* use it. I said you *could* use it to not reinvent the wheel.